# Update Recyclerview UI With Retrieved Socket Messages

Tags: android, sockets, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a chat app using nkzawa socket-io library. I have successfully sent messages to server and retrieved them in my log cat. I am unable to update the ui as the get message event was not done in the adapter.

I want to be able to separate the messages based on uid as mine or others and update ui properly. So far, I've been confused how to go about the adapter, should I retrieve the messages in adapter or in main UI?

Here's my adapter code:

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = MessagesAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Context context;

private DBHelper helper;
private TingTingUser user;

private List<HomeMessage> messageList;

public MessagesAdapter(Context context, List<HomeMessage> messageList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.messageList = messageList;
    helper = new DBHelper(context);
}

@Override
public MessagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View msgView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.messages_layout, parent, false);
    return new MessagesViewHolder(msgView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MessagesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    HomeMessage message = messageList.get(position);
    //holder.upDateUI();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (messageList.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return messageList.size();
}

public void upDateUI(String usersId) {
    user = helper.getCurrentUser(1);
    String currUid = user.getUserId();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_layout, null, false);

    MessagesViewHolder holder = new MessagesViewHolder(view);
    Log.d(TAG, "Uid form DB is:\t" + currUid);

    if (usersId != currUid) {
        holder.mainLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        holder.nameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.msgHolderLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.receiver_msg_bkg);
    } else {
        holder.mainLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        holder.nameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.msgHolderLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_msg_bkg);
    }

} }
```

Here's my method to retrieve all socket messages:

```
private void getPublicMessages(){

String get_event = "cc-" + chatRoomId;

Log.d(TAG, "Get Event Name is:\t " + get_event.toString());

mSocket.on(get_event, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) args[0];
                    //JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject();


                    String type = jsonObject.getString("type");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Message is of type:\t" + type);

                    JSONObject contentObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("content");

                    String userId = contentObject.getString("userId");
                    String roomId = contentObject.getString("roomId");
                    String message = contentObject.getString("message");
                    String name = contentObject.getString("name");
                    String avatar = contentObject.getString("avatar");

                    Log.d(TAG, "Get Message is:\t" + message);
                    Log.d(TAG, "roomId:\t" + roomId);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Get userId is:\t" + userId);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Get name is:\t" + name);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Get avatar is:\t" + avatar);


                    TingTingUser otherUsers = new TingTingUser(userId, "Abhiram Labhani", "Unknown");
                    HomeMessage othersHomeMessages = new HomeMessage(message, otherUsers, System.currentTimeMillis());

                    List<HomeMessage> othersList = new ArrayList<>();
                    othersList.add(othersHomeMessages);


                    Log.d(TAG, "Other Messages size is:\t " + othersList.size());

                    messageList.add(othersHomeMessages);
                    messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Log.d(TAG, "All Messages list size is:\t " + messageList.size());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

}
```

The values like name, message, etc are coming directly in activity. How should I update the ui, will this adapter code work or I should put this method in adapter and update accordingly?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to add the message received to the data source list you use in the Adapter.

Second thing you have to call

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemInserted(position)
```

OR

```
recycerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
```

second one is used to notify that multiple items are added.

Comment: I'll do just that but how do I bind these data from my logs to the recyclerview to display on the ui pls? Thanks

Comment: read about the RecyclerView https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html